# Как добавить все namespace для Unit-теста?

Tags: c#, .net, mvc, юнит-тесты

Как добавить namespace TestApp, TestApp.Controller, TestApp.View для Unit-проекта? При добавлении референса на TestApp, только он и доступен.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: используйте ключевое слово `using`, например `using mynamespace;`

Comment: @tym32167 Я знаю как подключать пространство. Дело в том что дальше первого TestApp, я не могу пройти к TespApp.Controller

Comment: а у вас в пространстве имен `TespApp.Controller` есть какие то публичные классы? Если да, то покажите их, покажите, как они определены и что они именно внктри `TespApp.Controller` пространства имен.

Comment: @tym32167 Благодарю. Не поставил модификатор public.